# How to know which View is being touched

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I'm trying to build a Ping Pong game, that the paddle is shown in the bottom of the screen and the bricks is on the top. I use three views, one for the paddle, one for the ball and another one that is the main view that paints the two views (ball and paddle):

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas){
    BallView.draw(canvas);
    PaddleView.draw(canvas);
}
```

What I want to know is if I can identify which view is being touched exactly, I try to do it with `onTouchEvent` in the main Activity:

```
   @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        Log.d("touched", "touched")
        return true;
    }
```

But, the problem is that no matter where I touch on the screen, the paddle is moving, and I want, that only when I touch the Paddle he will move.
SO, how can I do this, if it is possible?
Thanks.

Comment: Give both views a different id....                              private OnTouchListener tListener1 = new OnTouchListener(){
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)  than simply do   if(v.getId==R.id.blue) {} else if(v.getId==R.id.yellow){} I hope this will work.

Comment: @pakshaheen can I set the Id from the java file? because I don't have any XML file.

Comment: yes, you can do e.g. ScrollView view=new ScrollView(this);
        view.setId(2);

Comment: @pakshaheen Thanks, but the problem is that the OnTouchListener is never been called...

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this in another way like, just draw two relative layouts blue and yellow same as in your case and make it both relative layout as a clickable : true from the xml and handle the onClick:"onClickHandler". hope this will work for you.

```
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rl_click_blue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="onClickHandler">
                </RelativeLayout> 

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rl_click_yellow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="onClickHandler">
                </RelativeLayout> 

               // Handle your functionality here.
               public void onClickHandler(View v)
               {
                   switch (v.getId()) {
                       case R.id.rl_click_blue:
                           break;

                       case R.id.rl_click_yellow:

                          break;
                   }
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

Android's [OnTouch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch%28android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent%29) event already has a View type parameter with which you can identify the view that fired the event. You can find an example [here](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-4-setting-up-for-image-transformation/1785?tag=content;siu-container).