# imlement library that count the number of button click events in activity

Tags: android

I need to implement library that acts like Google's Analytic Tools - count the number of button click events in a activity.

I need to add only one line of code to the Activity (after on create) like :

```
MyTestLibrarySDK.start(this);
```

The library need to monitor the number of click events and save that count to a file.

The function is called before `setContextView` which mean there is no layout or view hierarchy yet.

I've tried to find a way to start a broadcast that notify  when the activity is loaded but couldn't find one.

Comment: Hi.. did u find anything related to this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a library that intercepts all touch events in that activity and that will check if the view touched is a button.

Some links that should guide you to the answer:

detecting touch events:
[How to detect touch events in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278247/how-to-detect-touch-events-in-android)

http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html

Handling them:

[handling touch events in Android when using multiple views/layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934932/handling-touch-events-in-android-when-using-multiple-views-layouts)

[Detect touch event on a view when dragged over from other view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980156/detect-touch-event-on-a-view-when-dragged-over-from-other-view)

[How to know which View is being touched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310050/how-to-know-which-view-is-being-touched)

[Can't get touch event detected on a view and click event detected on a parent view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991450/cant-get-touch-event-detected-on-a-view-and-click-event-detected-on-a-parent-vi)

Comment: I can't override activity function like dispatchTouchEvent() because I need all the work to be from the Library and not to add code to the activity